# Autoplay not working for html video even after muting and abiding by different browser rules

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, html5-video

So I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/swlh/add-a-background-video-to-your-landing-page-in-rails-5-7b9c459023bc) to a T on how to create a background banner video in a rails project. I've got it to show up on my home page the way I would like, but the autoplay is not working. I've tested out the other attributes, like loop and mute, and they work just fine. I read the rules that chrome has for autoplay regarding mute, and also tried the script tag using the javascript play method. Nothing appears to be working.

The only way I can get the video to play is if I add controls and then hit play, which is not the functionality that I am going for.

Does anybody know of anything else that might be holding up autoplay other than mute?

Here is my erb tags in my project

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <%= video_tag "type.mp4", mute: true, autoplay: :true, loop: true, class: "banner_video" %>
  <h1>Cheesy, inspiring coding caption here</h1>
</div>
```

I have also tried:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <%= video_tag "type.mp4", mute: :mute, autoplay: :autoplay, loop: :loop, class: "banner_video" %>
  <h1>Cheesy, inspiring coding caption here</h1>
</div>
```

And here is what it converts to:

```
<video mute="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" class="banner_video" src="/assets/type-7f0bdd6a4a5fe55ee8eefe5842020765eb1a05d78f50ca8279ed8b2e605c09ba.mp4"></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to embeded the video in this way?

```
<video id="player" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

For me, autoplay is working fine in Firefox.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. What does that mean that it works in Firefox but not chrome, and it also shows a broken video link in safari??